# modify register form in buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I have a theme called wplms, used for learning management system.

I need to allow instructors of courses to register in website directly as instructors (not students) and I need too that the administrator don't have to moderate each instructor’s registration.

For it, I’ve modified core of bp-members/bp-members-classes.php

In line 314, I have commented the line:

```
$wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE {$wpdb->users} SET user_status = 2 WHERE ID = %d", $user_id ) );
```

**because I want activate the user (instructor) just registered**

And in lines 319 and 320 I’ve commented:

```
delete_user_option( $user_id, ‘capabilities’ );
delete_user_option( $user_id, ‘user_level’ );
```

**because these lines are overwritting the wp_capalities that I previously defined.**

But I want to do this without modify the core. Could you give me a better way?
Thanks very much.

NOTE: I’ve noticed that the user registered appears in wp admin > users as instructors as well…but too as pendings…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**There is one hook**](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/buddypress/tags/2.0.1/bp-members/bp-members-classes.php#L342) when the method `add_backcompat()` returns its results. With it you could reverse what `$wpdb->query` and `delete_user_option` have done.

You have to find out what you need to fill the function:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (BP) Instructors registration adjustment
 */

add_filter( 'bp_core_signups_add_backcompat', 'bp_so_24199347' );

function bp_so_24199347( $user_id ) {
    // $wpdb->query( REVERT );
    // add_user_option( REVERT );

    return $user_id;
}
```